# Android JSON array through URL

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

im new and I making Android app which will be display info about items in Guild Wars 2 game. That data is here:
https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items
I need read whole list of this items (name, priece, icon) showing them like list view.
Problem is that i need modify url to specific item like:
https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/256
Is possible to acces to all items once?
My code :

```
package com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

ActorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items");

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
        }
    });
}


class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Wczytywanie prosze czekac");
        dialog.setTitle("Polaczenie z serwerem");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("256");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                    actor.setDob(object.getString("type"));
                    actor.setCountry(object.getString("level"));
                    actor.setHeight(object.getString("rarity"));
                    actor.setSpouse(object.getString("vendor_value"));
                    actor.setChildren(object.getString("default_skin"));
                    actor.setImage(object.getString("icon"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could use bulk expansion in this API prior to it's documentation.
[API documentation](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2)

But there are a problem that you can't use smthing like  https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/colors?ids=all for items. But you can get items by list of id's. This is for 10 items, for example: https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items?ids=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

So as I think you can write your code this way(where "n" is a number of all items):

```
String GET_ITEMS_URL = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items?ids="; 
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
     GET_ITEMS_URL += i + ",";
}
```

It is a little tricky, but it works as a solution for this API.